# How to separate functionality of tab pages from Qt main window class

Tags: qt, tabwidget

In my application, I have QTabWidget with 3 pages with controls designed in it, using Qt creator 2.4.1. now I want to separate the functionality of these pages from MainWindow by creating new classes.

My question is how to access the MainWindow::ui instance in my new class ? which is declared in private.

it is a qt-desktop application and platform is qt 4.8.1/win 7.

Comment: If you need to access `MainWindow::ui` from within the tabs, you haven't really separated the functionality.  This suggests that rethinking the design a bit further may be a good idea.

Comment: Yes I have not separated the functionality, any suggestions to design to achieve this ?

Comment: The details of how to do that are far beyond the scope of this type of forum - and without knowing much much more about it, nobody will be able to tell you how to do that. Start by asking yourself: "why does a tab need to know about the main ui?" Then you can either move the things it needed to know into the tab itself, or else pass the information through a function (or a `signal/slot` connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly access ui of MainWindow in your tabs. As your QTabWidget is child of MainWindow (This is how it should be implemented and assume you did so).

But you can achieve this by Signals and Slots.You can perform operations in your MainWindow by writing slots to signals emitted from individual tabs.

**OR**

You can write a method on the MainWindow which will operate on it's UI. And call it from the tab widget by-

```
this->parent->parent->uiMethod();

// this(Tab) -> parent(QTabWidget) -> parent(MainWindow) -> [related method]
```

Comment: I am already using signals and slots for many controls in tabs, since there is many controls present in these 3 tab pages, my MainWindow.cpp is quit big with the code implemented for all controls. so that I want to split the functionality for each tabs. I am not sure about the second solution you gave will solve my problem. or am I missing anything to understand your solution ?

Comment: If you have controls in your individual tabs then, can't you handle them in those tabs itself?? Try to make less dependency on MainWindow by signals and slots.

Comment: Ok, I was having one ui file with all the controls in it, now I split the functionality into separate classes and now its easy to maintain with signals and slots. thanks.